# wxpython > DatePickerCtrl obj - How can I convert 'year' from 2 digits into 4 digits?

Tags: python, datepicker, wxpython

**PROBLEM**

> In GUI DatePickerCtrl obj, the date format is: mm/dd/yyyy
>
> if I get the DatePickerCtrl obj value, the date format is: mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss

**CODE snippet**

```
datePicker = wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl( frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime)
print datePicker.GetValue() # This outputs  11/20/15 14:20:55
```

I can convert to string and slice `[:-8]` but I cannot convert **'15'** into **'2015'**

**CURRENT**

```
11/20/15
```

**DESIRED**

```
11/20/2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetValue` method of `DatePickerCtrl` returns `wx.DateTime` object so answer is simple like below.

```
dpc = wx.DatePickerCtrl(self)
datetime_obj = dpc.GetValue()
datetime_obj.GetYear()  # -> returns year as four digit integer
```

Here is a [link](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DateTime-class.html) for `wx.DateTime`. You can get the month (`GetMonth()`) and day (`GetDay()`), hour, minute, etc. easily as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use wx.DateTime.Format()

```
datePicker = wx.DatePickerCtrl( frame, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultDateTime)
sel_date = datePicker.GetValue()
print sel_date.Format("%d-%m-%Y")
```

p.s. what is adv doing in the middle of wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl ?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

```
import time
fullTime = str(datePicker.GetValue())[:-8]
print fullTime
firstHalf = fullTime[:6]
print "firstHalf is: " , firstHalf
secondHalf = fullTime[-3:]
print "secondHalf", secondHalf
year = int(secondHalf)
if 59 <= year <= 99:
  secondHalf = '19' + secondHalf
else:
  secondHalf = '20' + secondHalf
print "altered_secondHalf", secondHalf
finalTime = firstHalf + secondHalf
print finalTime
```